# Thread1 signal SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm having a problem I need to resolve it fast really fast!

2014-07-04 11:04:00.649 GetItDone[44901:60b] -[AppDelegate getTaskListRecords]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e36670
2014-07-04 11:04:00.657 GetItDone[44901:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate getTaskListRecords]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e36670'

This is my code!

TaskListViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

coreDataFunctions = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

self.tasks = [coreDataFunctions getTaskListRecords];

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

CoreDataFunctions.h

```
@interface CoreDataFunctions : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void) saveContext;
- (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory;

- (NSMutableArray *) getTaskListRecords;

@end
```

Everything was working and puff it failed after I added a picker to the story board.

Comment: It seems that you are sending getTaskListRecords message to AppDelegate instance but it is implemented in CoreDataFunctions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an outlet that doesn't have a corresponding value in the Entity (such as that new picker). That's the "unrecognized selector"